# Can't hide overflow-x

Tags: html, css

So, I have a theme where body width is limited, and where I want a full width background for a header element. Below is the code I tried.

I stacked one div onto another and gave them this CSS:

```
#topcontainer {
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   min-height:56px;
   background-color:#D8D8D8 !important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #BCBCBD;
   z-index:22 !important;
   color:black;
}

#topcontainer2 {
   width:140%;
   min-height:56px;
   margin-left:-20%;
   position:absolute;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   background-color:#D8D8D8 !important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #BCBCBD;
   z-index:-1;
}
```

I still see the horizontal scroller. How do I get rid of it?

JSfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/soloveich/A7tYn/

Comment: Post your HTML and a jsFiddle.

Comment: added fiddle to the post

Comment: will this work? http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/LxNKg/

Comment: no. there would still be blank space on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this rule to your css works:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `overflow: hidden;` instead of `overflow-x: hidden`?

Comment: is it possible to remove the `width: 140%`?

Comment: No. I'm gonna have to rewrite the whole theme. Body width is limited.